Is the "ぐらい" always needed in "どのぐらいかかりますか?"
The examples that I see regarding asking how long something (e.g. a train ride) takes always translates to "どのぐらいかかりますか?".
But from what I understand, "ぐらい" means "about (how much time)". E.g. "十分ぐらいかかります" (it takes about 10 minutes) compared to "十分かかります" (it takes 10 minutes).
So "どのぐらいかかりますか?" actually translates to "about how long it takes?"?
Then what if I want to get a more precise answer (not just roughly how long)? Can I ask "どのかかりますか?"?

The short answer is no.  You can't just ask どのかかりますか.
どの works like この, その, and あの.  It needs to proceed a noun.  In this case, the noun is くらい (位).  Without a noun, you'll have to say something like いくら in place of どのくらい.
The longer answer is that though くらい is a suffix applied to various expressions to indicate an approximation, in certain set phrases like どのくらい it is important to understand the function of these two parts: どの and くらい.  In function どの wants to attach to a noun.  The word that functions as noun in this case is くらい.  While in my Japanese dictionary indicates that くらい alone can be analyzed as an adverbial particle ([副助詞]{ふくじょし}), in this particular construction it corresponds with the noun 位.

Thanks. Then... (1) Is it still correct to say "十分かかります" (i.e. without the ぐらい)? (2) Even when I ask "どのぐらいかかいますか?", I am simply asking "how much time does it take" and not an approximation?

@PieFaced Yes, you could answer that way.

Can I ask "どのかかりますか?"  So, no, you can't just say that.

@istrasci I've updated the answer.  I assume you were pointing out that my answer was unclear.

@A.Ellett:  No, not at all.  Just that OP's question that I quoted was not explicitly answered, so I wanted to make sure they weren't still uncertain about it.

どの must come before a noun, as explained in A.Ellet's answer, just like この, その and あの. So the answer is: no, どのかかりますか? does not make sense.
However, there are some alternative ways to ask the roughly same thing without the ぐらい:

どんなにかかりますか？
いくらかかりますか？
どれだけかかりますか？

However, answering these with an estimated amount (e.g. with ぐらい) is still valid, just like the "How long will it take" (without using "about" in the question) still allows an approximated estimate as an answer. If you mean to ask "Precisely how long", you need to add an adverb to that question:

正確にいくらかかりますか？
きっかりどれだけかかりますか？
ちょうど何分{なんふん}かかりますか？

If they only have an approximate estimate, this will at least make it very likely that they'll answer with something like "I don't have the exact estimate, but it will be about 10 min".
